# Application state with Xcode7 UI testing

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing, uitest

Is it possible to get application state(`UIApplicationState`) of the application that I am testing while executing the UI Tests.

Actually I want write UITest for following scenario -
For one of the operation my application switches to another application, I want to test whether my application had switched or not. I was thinking of achieving it by monitoring the application state of my app.

Comment: In general, switching between applications is not supported at all.